# Twitter Helper class is not present in System.Web.Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, twitter, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to use Asp .net Webpages for my site. I am following [W3Schools' tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/webpages_ref_helpers.asp) for this. I started with Empty Asp .net application project and added a cshtml page to it. After too many trouble I finally installed System.Web.Helpers package from nuget and it's working for GamerCard.

The problem is I am not able to use Twitter helpers at all. I am getting the following error when I use `Twitter.Profile()`

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Twitter' does not exist in the current context

I used Object Browser to check the System.Web.Helpers assembly and to much of my surprise there was no Twitter class at all. I can see Facebook, GamerCard, Gravatar etc. classes, but no sign of Twitter there. Acc. to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers%28VS.99%29.aspx), Twitter class should be present there too.

Any idea what did I miss?

Comment: and you have `using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;`?

Comment: @gunr2171 Not sure where to put that. Is it required?

Comment: Well, I did a little reasearch, found that (and is shown in your msdn link) that Twitter is in the `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` namespace, and is avalible from the [ASP.NET Web Helpers Library package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/). However, when I installed it, I am having the exact same problem as you are.

Comment: But it also looks like the [namespace might have changed](http://forums.asp.net/post/5173949.aspx).

Comment: The System.Web.Helpers doesn't have twitter at all. Anyways I've found the answer. Posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on [Codeplex project](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com) site of Asp.net. The issue mentioned [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1088), stats that due to the retirement of Twitter API V1, the Twitter helper code was broken, hence Microsoft removed it from the `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` namespace completely. More info can be found in the issue text.

To use twitter helpers, the issue mentions a newer and more complex method which you can see [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/twitter-helper). Didn't try it yet, but I hope it'll work.

Thanks @gunr2171 for helping and pushing in the right direction :-)